# raise ExtractorError('Could not find JS function %r' % funcname) youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: Could not find JS function 'na'

Tags: python

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\hello\bot> & C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/hutao/hutao_command.py
```

We have logged in as hutao#5005
ERROR: Signature extraction failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\youtube.py", line 1348, in _decrypt_signature
func = self._extract_signature_function(
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\youtube.py", line 1262, in _extract_signature_function
res = self._parse_sig_js(code)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\youtube.py", line 1331, in _parse_sig_js
initial_function = jsi.extract_function(funcname)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\jsinterp.py", line 245, in extract_function
raise ExtractorError('Could not find JS function %r' % funcname)

## Heading

youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: Could not find JS function 'na'
(caused by ExtractorError("Could not find JS function 'na'"))

Comment: Here is an issue in the youtube-dl repo https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/30378

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this exact same problem on version 2021.6.6 which I was using but decided to upgrade using this command:

```
pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

It downloaded version 2021.12.17 which seems to work fine, I can download videos as usual now.

Answer (score 0):

Same error try using yt-dlp instead. The usage is same just import the modules you imported from youtube-dl. SHORTCUT: replace youtube_dl where ever you see it in your code by yt-dlp. But first install it.